# Whats the difference between a resource limit and a resource max in Limit Range? And request vs min?

Tags: kubernetes

LimitRange allows us to configure these properties per resource (memory, CPU):

- **Limit**: default maximum ammount of the resource that will be provisioned.
- **Request**: default initial ammount of the resource that will be provisioned.

However I just realized there are two other options, min and max. Since min/max seem to overlap with request/limit, what the difference between all these properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer digging in [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-constraint-namespace/#motivation-for-minimum-and-maximum-memory-constraints). Limit and Request params are overridable by the pod configurations. Min and Max enforce the values configured in the LimitRange:

> Motivation for minimum and maximum memory constraints
>
> As a cluster administrator, you might want to impose restrictions on
>   the amount of memory that Pods can use. For example:
>
> Each Node in a cluster has 2 GB of memory. You do not want to accept any Pod that requests more than 2 GB of memory, because no Node
>   in the cluster can support the request.
>
> A cluster is shared by your production and development departments. You want to allow production workloads to consume up to 8
>   GB of memory, but you want development workloads to be limited to 512
>   MB. You create separate namespaces for production and development, and
>   you apply memory constraints to each namespace.